# How to create an ASP.NET Core MVC form with a list of check boxes and a submit button? Issue with model binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a form where a user can select check boxes in a table of products. I want the boxes checked to be stored but there seems to be an issue with the model binding. When I run the debugger, the parameter products for the Submit action is always empty. Here is what I have right now:

**Model:**

```
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool Used { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ProductCVE> CVE { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
        private readonly IProductRepository _repo;
        public ProductsController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
        // GET: ProductsController
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = _repo.FindAll().ToList();
            return View(products);
        }
        // POST: ProductsController
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Submit(IEnumerable<Products> products)
        {
            foreach(Products prod in products)
            {
                _repo.Update(prod);
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<KB_Collector_API.Models.Products>
@addTagHelper*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Products</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="RunScript">Import Monthly Update</a>
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Products", "POST"))
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CVE)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Used)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var product in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-controller="ProductCVE" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@product.ID">Details</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => product.Used)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firsly,you need know that for each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix.Your backend wants to receive `IEnumerable<Products>` which is a list model. so what you pass should be `[index].PropertyName`.

What you did will render checkbox with name `product.Used`, it does not match the `Products` model. Change your html:

```
@model List<Products>   //change here....

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Products", "POST"))
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Description)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].CVE)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Used)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="ProductCVE" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="@Model[i].ID">Details</a>
                </td>
                <td>                                  //importance here...
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].Used)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

If you want to **post all the properties displayed in the html**, you also need to add hidden input for `Description` property, because `DisplayFor` jsut render a text in html, it cannot be passed to backend:

```
<td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Description)
     <input hidden asp-for="@Model[i].Description"/>
</td>
```